How to Map Kiwi TCMS Fields to Jira Fields Automatically?
I'm currently working with Kiwi TCMS and have successfully integrated it with Jira through the "Add Bug Tracker" feature. The integration works smoothly – whenever we click "Report Bug" in Kiwi TCMS, a new issue is created in Jira.
However, I want to take this integration a step further by automatically mapping specific fields from Kiwi TCMS to Jira fields when an issue is created. Here’s an example of the mappings I’d like to implement:
Kiwi TCMS Field Jira Field
Reporter to Reporter
Product to Components
Category to Labels
The goal is for these fields to be populated in Jira without manual intervention whenever a new bug is reported from Kiwi TCMS.
My questions are:
Is it possible to set up automatic field mapping from Kiwi TCMS to Jira?
If yes, how can we implement it? Is there any configuration or customization that can be applied to achieve this?
Are there any plugins or scripts (maybe using the Jira API) that would facilitate this kind of field mapping?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
I successfully integrated Kiwi TCMS with Jira by adding a Bug Tracker in the Kiwi TCMS settings. The integration itself works well; when I click "Report Bug" in Kiwi TCMS, a Jira issue is automatically created.
To achieve field mapping, I explored the following options:
Kiwi TCMS Configuration: I checked the Kiwi TCMS documentation to see if there are settings for direct field mapping to Jira fields, but I couldn’t find any clear solutions.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
